# INSERT EPOCH AND Unix TimeStamp between 2 dates

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an small issue, I have a insert SQL statement which is like follows:

```
INSERT INTO table (`col`, `col`, `col`)
    VALUES '1', '2', FLOOR(950000+RAND()*(550000-950000));
```

One of the columns is a EPOCH Unix TImeStamp, I want to be able to RANDOMIZE INSERTS between 2 dates: so for example:

RANDOMIZED INSERT VALUE BETWEEN: 1469696000 and 1479996000

how can I achieve this using RAND but set the condition so it must be between those values so when its converter its between those EPOCH dates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give it a try:

```
INSERT INTO table (`col`, `col`, `col`)
    VALUES '1', '2', (FLOOR( 1469696000 + RAND( ) *(1479996000-1469696000 )))
```

**Note:**

```
(FLOOR( A + RAND( ) * B)) will return a random number between A and A+B (inclusive)
```

**EDIT:**

In order to get `Random` unix timestamp between `now` and end of this year:

```
(FLOOR( UNIX_TIMESTAMP() + RAND( ) *(UNIX_TIMESTAMP((CURDATE() - INTERVAL DAYOFYEAR(CURDATE()) DAY) + INTERVAL 1 YEAR) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP())))
```

So here's the full query:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE (
    `col`,
    `col`,
    `col`
)
VALUES
    '1',
    '2',
    (
        FLOOR(
            UNIX_TIMESTAMP() + RAND() * (
                UNIX_TIMESTAMP(
                    (
                        CURDATE() - INTERVAL DAYOFYEAR(CURDATE()) DAY
                    ) + INTERVAL 1 YEAR
                ) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
            )
        )
    )
```

Comment: This does work but the issue is for example I have just inserted and its inserted a value of 2282859127 which is a date in 2042. I need a range in EPOCH to be between now and the end of the year?

Comment: please check now. I made a mistake then.

Comment: Thanks you are awesome.